# Vuejs unit tests: Cannot call text on an empty DOMWrapper

Tags: vue.js, vue-test-utils

I'm using vue test utils to test  a component and getting this error trying to test a text. Cannot call text on an empty DOMWrapper.

UPDATED CODE.
getting "  RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" in atable.spec.ts test.

atable.spec.ts

```
import ATable from "../components/ATable.vue";
import { IPatientResponse } from "@/types/patients";
import { shallowMount, RouterLinkStub } from "@vue/test-utils";

it("renders proper texts.", () => {
  const wrapper = shallowMount(ATable, {
    props: {
      patients: [
        {
          id: 1,
          firstName: "arpit",
          lastName: "satyal",
          email: "arpited7@gmail.com",
          contact: "12345",
          address: "ktm",
          dob: "1998-07-29",
          allergies: ["Pet allergies"],
        },
      ] as IPatientResponse[],
    },
    stubs: {
      RouterLink: RouterLinkStub,
    },
    scopedSlots: {
      bodyCell: `
          <template slot-scope="{ column, record }" v-if="column.key === 'firstName'">
          <router-link :to="{ name: 'PatientProfile', params: { id: record.id } }">
            <div id="test-patient">{{ record.firstName }} {{ record.lastName }}</div>
          </router-link>
        </template>`,
    }
  });
  const patientNameSelector = wrapper.find("#test-patient");
  // see if the message renders
  expect(patientNameSelector.text()).toEqual("arpit satyal");
});
```

atable.vue
refactored the table component to be it's own component. it now recieves props from dashboard component.

```
<!-- eslint-disable vue/multi-word-component-names -->
<template>
  <section>
    <a-table :columns="columns" :data-source="patients" :pagination="false">
      <template #bodyCell="{ column, record }">
        <template v-if="column.key === 'firstName'">
          <router-link :to="{ name: 'PatientProfile', params: { id: record.id } }">
            <span id="test-patient">{{ record.firstName }} {{ record.lastName }}</span>
          </router-link>
        </template>
        <template v-else-if="column.key === 'specialAttention'">
          <span class="pointer">
            <EyeOutlined
              v-if="record.specialAttention"
              @click="markAsSpecial(record, false)"
              class="iconStyle"
            />
            <EyeInvisibleOutlined
              v-else
              @click="markAsSpecial(record, true)"
              class="iconStyle"
            />
          </span>
        </template>

        <template v-else-if="column.key === 'action'">
          <span class="pointer">
            <router-link :to="{ name: 'UpdatePatient', params: { id: record.id } }">
              <EditOutlined style="margin-right: 10px" class="iconStyle" />
            </router-link>
            <a-divider type="vertical" />
            <DeleteOutlined @click="deletePatient(record.id)" class="iconStyle" />
            <a-divider type="vertical" />
          </span>
        </template>
      </template>
    </a-table>
  </section>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import {
  EditOutlined,
  DeleteOutlined,
  EyeInvisibleOutlined,
  EyeOutlined,
} from "@ant-design/icons-vue";
import { defineComponent } from "@vue/runtime-core";

const columns = [
  {
    title: "Name",
    dataIndex: "firstName",
    key: "firstName",
    align: "center",
  },
  {
    title: "Contact",
    dataIndex: "contact",
    key: "contact",
    align: "center",
  },
  {
    title: "Address",
    dataIndex: "address",
    key: "address",
    align: "center",
  },
  {
    title: "DOB",
    key: "dob",
    dataIndex: "dob",
    align: "center",
  },
  {
    title: "Special Attention",
    key: "specialAttention",
    align: "center",
  },
  {
    title: "Actions",
    key: "action",
    align: "center",
  },
];
export default defineComponent({
  props: ["deletePatient", "markAsSpecial", "patients"],
  components: {
    EditOutlined,
    DeleteOutlined,
    EyeInvisibleOutlined,
    EyeOutlined,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      columns,
    };
  },
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are testing *Dashboard* component and trying to check that *ATable* (`<a-table>`) component rendered slot content that was passed to it. This is wrong.
Considering *ATable* component all you should check while testing *Dashboard* component is that the *ATable* component just was rendered. That's it.

```
// In Dashboard.spec.js
it("renders ATable component.", () => {
  const ATableStub = {
    template: '<div>ATableStub</div>' 
  }
    const wrapper = shallowMount(Dashboard, {
      stubs: {
        ATable: ATableStub
      },
      data() {
        return {
          patients: [
            {
              id: 1,
              firstName: "arpit",
              lastName: "satyal",
              email: "arpited7@gmail.com",
              contact: "12345",
              address: "ktm",
              dob: "1998-07-29",
              allergies: ["Pet allergies"],
            },
          ] as IPatientResponse[],
        };
      },
    });
wrapper.findComponent(ATableStub).exists.toBe(true);
  });
});
```

You should leave testing *ATable*'s slot content to tests for *ATable* component, not *Dashboard* component.

```
// In ATable.spec.js
import { shallowMount, RouterLinkStub } from '@vue/test-utils'

  it("renders proper texts.", () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(ATable, {
      stubs: {
        RouterLink: RouterLinkStub
      },
      scopedSlots: {
        bodyCell: `
          <template slot-scope="{ column, record }" v-if="column.key === 'firstName'">
          <router-link :to="{ name: 'PatientProfile', params: { id: record.id } }">
            <div id="test-patient">{{ record.firstName }} {{ record.lastName }}</div>
          </router-link>
        </template>`
      },
      data() {
        return {
          patients: [
            {
              id: 1,
              firstName: "arpit",
              lastName: "satyal",
              email: "arpited7@gmail.com",
              contact: "12345",
              address: "ktm",
              dob: "1998-07-29",
              allergies: ["Pet allergies"],
            },
          ] as IPatientResponse[],
        };
      },
    });
    const patientNameSelector = wrapper.find("#test-patient");
    // see if the message renders
    expect(patientNameSelector.text()).toEqual("arpit satyal");
  });
});
```

Comment: still not working. I updated the post with entire component....

Comment: Hi @Eduardo, I updated the code, now getting a different error "  RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" can you check above code and reply?

Comment: @Arpit hi! You should not create your own ```ATable``` component, it already exists in AntDesign, you should just import it to your ```.spec``` file.

Comment: how do I import "ATable"? ant design has "Table", do you mean that?

Comment: I don't know the exact name but I see you are using ```<a-table ```, that component you should import from AntDesign.